# What's the name for equations that never solves to a number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology

This has always been difficult for me to understand. I always think that algebra's final solution must be a number.

I don't know why.

Take a look at this equation,

$$x_3+y_3+z_3=k$$

Someone can solve the $k$ in equation as follows,

$$3x + 3y + 3z = k$$

$$k = 3x  + 3y + 3z$$

However, this has never been a solution for my brain because I never find a number.

I found an article claiming that the supercomputer solved the number for the equation.

So, this is not the only equation I have come across and I have found many.

So the name of this kind of equations are called as unsolvable problems? Does Academia have a better name than that?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Is this question a bad fit for this SE?

Comment: @curiousalgbra : did you read the link JoseCarlos sent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a type of question where we express the variable of interest in terms of the other variables. Typically, we isolate the variable on one side.

The implication of this is that if the other variables' values are known to us, then we can find the corresponding value for our variable of interest. With the other variable not known, $k$ indeed remains unknown.

Another example: Solve for $x$ if $ax^2+bx+c=0$.

The general solution is $$x = \frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

Whenever you know $a,b,c$, you identify your $x$. A single formula can be used to  solve all the quadratic equation.

Comment: Why do schools give such equations to students if they are unsolvable? What's the purpose?

Comment: It is an important thing to learn.  You learn how to express a variable in terms of the other variables, hence you know that if you can identify the rest, you would have solved the exact value. For example $E=mc^2$ tells you that if you know $m$ and $c$, you can determine $E$.   Conversely, if you know $E$, how do you solve for $m$? it helps you understand such question. Also, by expressing them in terms of variables, you can write a program to automate such stuff.

Comment: @curiousalgbra : it is not about getting a single answer, unsolvable is not the correct term here, there are either infinitely many solution, finitely many solution or no values that can satisfy the equations, it is a good test of logic and mathematical reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I sort of understand what you're getting to. In your example,

```
             3x+3y+3z = k  --> k = 3x+3y+3z
```

is just following the commutative rule of algebra, and, like you said, you will never get a real "answer," because what that did was just flip the equation backwards. That equation, much like most of the ones that exist, need some sort of input(s) to give it context, if that makes any sense. If there aren't any inputs, you're not going to get past the variables.

There are so many examples of these types of equations, but some examples are the quadratic formula, RREF (not a formula but has the same idea) and the Pythagorean theorem.

I hope this helps!